# How To add Expander.header dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I don't know How to name this, so I don't know what to google for, so I decided to ask here.

My XAML Code is:

```
<Expander ExpandDirection="Right">
    <Expander.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="PC and Notebook" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Expander.Header>
    <TreeView>

    </TreeView>
</Expander>
```

So I want to make this XAML Code into Code-Behind (for a while loop).
I started simple with:

```
Expander cat_expander = new Expander();
cat_expander.ExpandDirection = ExpandDirection.Right;
```

And my problem now is. How to add `<Expander.Header>` dynamically ? How people name this thing when a Control has another control inside it?

I hope u can understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `Header` property to a `TextBlock`:

```
Expander cat_expander = new Expander();
cat_expander.ExpandDirection = ExpandDirection.Right;
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = "PC and Notebook";
textBlock.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
textBlock.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = 90 };
cat_expander.Header = textBlock;
cat_expander.Content = new TreeView();
```

Comment: thanks. this helped me a lot. So Expander.Header is a property of Expander.